# Is it a good design to call private methods inside a constructor?

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor, initialization

Say I have the following class:

```
public class FormContainer {

    @EJB
    private ExternalDao externalDao; // uses dependency Injection

    private final OrderForm orderForm;

    private final List<OrderFormContent> formContents;

    public FormContainer(OrderForm orderForm) {
        this.orderForm = orderForm
        initializeOrderForm();
    }

    private void initializeOrderForm() {
        formContents = externalDao.getFormContents(orderForm);
        // similar for any other properties
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

I am using this class to be able to hold all the fields that I will need to refer through the application. I am still learning good design and bad design practices so I am wondering if this bad design to initialize the properties of orderForm.

If so, how could it be improved?

Comment: In principle, calling private methods from a constructor is fine. But you can't use them to initialize final fields... and I'm not seeing any particular benefit from extracting the method in this particular case.

Comment: `how could it be improved?` by not calling a method on a null object. `externalDao`

Comment: should've been more obvious externalDao gets injected.

Comment: I am using final fields bc the values won't change since this class would be used with a singleton to hold the values for a particular form. @JonSkeet

Comment: You still can't assign values to final fields from methods though... It's just against the language rules.

Comment: its ok to have fields or methods in constructor in order to initialize. you use methods in constructor in order not to repeat your code but if you want to do a business inside your class  its better to reconsider your design

Answer (score 6):

It's OK.

The important rule to remember is not to allow `this` to "escape", which means don't let the instance be passed, directly or implicitly due to anonymous/inner classes, to another "process" (defined in the broadest terms).

The reason is that your instance may not be completely initialized when the other process gets it, which can lead to inconsistencies and weird bugs.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to call private methods from your constructor to initialize some data that used inside the class. Just be sure that your methods have no "side-effects" like long-time methods that user of your class would probably not expect with just calling your constructor.

If you have such methods, maybe you should extract Inititialize method that user of your class will use when he will be ready for it.